# Formatting individual characters in a cell - inexplicable behavior

Tags: excel, vba

I have code in a macro that formats individual characters in a cell. Recently, it has stopped working, and only formats all the characters or none at all.

I have reduced the code to just a few lines to test, and it fails on two different machines (one Mac, one PC). I've restarted many times. Both machines exhibit the same incorrect behavior.

```
Sub formattest()
    Workbooks("Text.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Characters(Start:=1, Length:=1).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Workbooks("Text.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Characters(Start:=1, Length:=1).Font.Bold = True
End Sub

Sub formattest2()
    Workbooks("Text.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Characters(1, 1).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Workbooks("Text.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Characters(1, 1).Font.Bold = True
End Sub

Sub formattest3()
    With Workbooks("Text.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Characters(1, 1).font
        .Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .Bold = True
    End With
End Sub
```

In all three subroutines, I expect only the first character in cell 1,1 to be formatted, but that is not what happens. I thought it was specific to Excel getting into a strange state, which is why I tried on two different machines and restarted. What happened and why did it once work but no longer does? Is there anything I can do to achieve the behavior I want?

Comment: What is the text in that cell?

Comment: Your code work fine for me. Is it still incorrect if you designate the cell a different way like using Select or Activecell or Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1))?  I'd say try Control Panel>Programs>Microsoft Office>Repair, but you've already tested on a different machine so I doubt that would help.

Comment: I think you just got to the bottom of it.  I had been using numbers with spaces between (when it was working), but now I just use numbers (which I'm using as strings).  Alpha characters work with individual character formatting, but not numbers.  But I've just been unsuccessfully trying to format a number in a way that it works (like with Text formatting) but I haven't gotten it to work yet. . . .

Comment: It doesn't work with numbers like that, unless you change the cell format to text or add an apostrophe in front of the number. Otherwise I think you're out of luck.

Comment: BigBen I think it works now.  I formatted the cell as a text cell and all is good.  Thank you so much for pointing out the issue.  Thank you for your comment as well Stax.

Answer (score 1):

Just to close this question out: You'll run into this issue if you try to format distinct digits of a number, as opposed to characters in text.

To circumvent this, either change the format of the cell to *Text*, or add an apostrophe `'` before the number to force it to text.

If you have to retain the number as a number, and not text, I think it's impossible.